# How to programmatically pause after Sitecore item creation until index is updated

Tags: indexing, sitecore

A coworker asked this question, and I wasn't immediately finding a solution, so I'm posting it here. He is programmatically inserting a Sitecore item in the master DB, and then subsequently has to insert another item that has a dependency on the first item being present in the index. He originally was having that second item insert fail every time or two, but has since inserted a manual pause in his code to try to allow the index time to catch up, and it's now failing only about every tenth time. Better, but not perfect.

He is looking for whether there's a Sitecore way to check for if the index has been updated before he proceeds with inserting the dependent item.

I did find this blog post by Alex Shyba (http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/04/search-index-troubleshooting.html), which looks like it might have some applicability, but my coworker is strictly working in the master DB (no publishing involved), and we already have the first several steps in Alex's article implemented in our solution (I didn't go through the whole thing).

Answer (score 2):

If you are dependent on an index add, in the end the only way to ensure the item is in the index is to take the action following the asynchronous index update. And in Sitecore 6, the only way to do that which I am aware of is the `database:propertychanged event`. [Alex Shyba describes this event in another article](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2012/07/sync-up-sitecore-search-index-update.html), with regard to HTML cache clearing.

Your challenge will likely be knowing in the event handler what item was inserted, and what to do with it. You'll need some sort of global data structure to communicate this state information, since the index update runs as an asynch job.

Other options (which may be easier) would be to remove the dependency on the index update (use Sitecore query or fast query), or poll the index until the item is there (which is a bit ugly).

Comment: Thanks much, Nick -- he's checking out this info.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add the item the index yourself? That way the UI will be blocked until its done.

You could do it by hooking into the item:saved event. I'm thinking the event handler would be based on the code from the database crawler

Comment: Thanks, Colin, I've passed on the FYI to him.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about queuing the second task as a "timed task", with some wrapper to check the dependency and requeue if necessary? See http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/All-About-Sitecore-Scheduling-Agents-and-Tasks.aspx.